# Missing $ inserted inside matrix

Tags: errors

I'm getting "missing $ inserted" (along with a lot of other nearby errors, but that's the first one) on this snippet:

```
$$
(\tilde A-\lambda)^m =
\begin{blockarray}{(cccc)}
        \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{(A-\lambda)^m}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots} \\
        & & & & \\ \\
        0 & \dots & 0 & (1-\lambda)^m
\end{blockarray}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Specifically, it's at the line

```
\BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{(A-\lambda)^m}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots}
```

I can't find a way to see exactly *where* the $ was inserted, but either way I have no idea why there would be one there. The code renders fine, the error is just bothering me.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Hello! What is `blockarray`? And where is `pmatrix` started? And heck, could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You need to inform us of what `\BAmulticolumn` looks like. In fact, instead of providing us with only a code snippet, show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: The `\end{pmatrix}` was a typo, removing it hasn't changed the issue, though. I actually *couldn't* provide a MWE because I really have no idea what I'm doing - I copy pasted this snippet and modified it using my limited knowledge of TeX until it (mostly) worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing the `$` in the `\multirow` and had an extraneous `\end{pmatrix}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I replaced the `$$...$$` with `\[ ... \]`. As Werner pointed out, please see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).
- The `$` were required in the option to `\multirow` as that parameter is assumed to be in text mode. Using the `$` ensures that math mode is used.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
(\tilde A-\lambda)^m =
\begin{blockarray}{(cccc)}
        \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{$(A-\lambda)^m$}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\vdots} \\
        & & & & \\ \\
        0 & \dots & 0 & (1-\lambda)^m
\end{blockarray}
%\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain why $s are needed in the `\multirow`? Does the  `\begin{blockmatrix}` break out of math mode?

Comment: @JackM: Added brief explanation.

Comment: A simple `pmatrix` will produce the same result.The `blkarray` environment is designed for block matrices.

Answer (score 4):

You need neither `multirow` nor `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
(\tilde A-\lambda)^m =
\begin{pmatrix}
(A-\lambda)^m & \vdots\vphantom{\Bigg|} \\
\begin{matrix}0 & \dots & 0\end{matrix} & (1-\lambda)^m
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not just `0 \quad\dots\quad 0` for the first part of the second line, and why is the extra height needed with the `\Bigg|`? adding an optional space `[2\jot]` (or even a bit more) would put the extra space only between the lines where it's really wanted.  (or am i missing something?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wanted to reproduce the same spacing made by `pmatrix`, so a nested `matrix` seems best. The space above `(A-\lambda)^m` is probably meant for making clear that it's a submatrix, rather than a row.